# Performance settings for ActiveMQ producer using Apache Camel in Spring boot framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We have a spring boot application and we are using apache camel as a framework for message processing. We are trying to best optimize our application settings to make the enqueue of messages on the ActiveMQ queue fast which is received by the Logstash on the other end of the queue as consumers.

The documentation is scattered at many places and there are too many configurations available.

For example, the [camel link for spring boot](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/activemq-starter.html) specifies 102 options. Similarly, the [activemq apache camel link](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/activemq-component.html) details these with much more.

This is what we have currently configured:

**Application.properties:**

```
################################################
# Spring Active MQ
################################################
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

**Apache Camel**

```
.to("activemq:queue:"dataQueue"?messageConverter=#queueMessageConverter");
```

**Problem:**

1 - We suspect that we have to use poolConnectionFactory and not default Spring JMS Template bean which is somehow auto picked up.

2 - We also want the process to be asynchornous. We just want to put the message on queue and dont want to wait for any ACK from activemq or do anyretry or something.

3 - We want to wait for retry only if queue is full.

4 - Where should we set the settings for ActiveMq size? and also the activemq is putting things in Dead letter queue in case no consumer availaible? We want to override that behaviour and want to keep the message in there. (Is this have to be configured in Activemq and not in Our app/apache camel)

**Update**
Here is we have solved it after some more investigation and based on feedback for now. Note: this does not involve retrying, for that we will try the option suggested in the answer.

**For Seda queues:**

producer:

```
.to("seda:somequeue?waitForTaskToComplete=Never");
```

consumer:

```
.from("seda:somequeue?concurrentConsumers=20");
```

Active MQ:

```
.to("activemq:queue:dataQueue?disableReplyTo=true);
```

Application.Properties:

```
#Enable poolconnection factory
spring.activemq.pool.enabled=true
spring.activemq.pool.blockIfFull=true
spring.activemq.pool.max-connections=50
```

Comment: You're asking about too many issues here. Each question should focus on a single issue. Also, have you considered using [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/)? Overall performance is quite a bit better with ActiveMQ Artemis than with ActiveMQ 5.x, especially as the number of clients scales up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you need to use pooledConnectionFactory. Especially with Camel+Spring Boot. Or look to use the camel-sjms component. The culprit is Spring's JMSTemplate. Super high latency.
2. Send NON_PERSISTENT and AUTO_ACK, also turn on sendAsync on the connection factory
3. You need to catch javax.jms.ResourceAllocationException in your route to do retries when Producer Flow Control kicks in (aka queue or broker is full)
4. ActiveMQ does sizing based on bytes, not message count. See the SystemUsage settings in [Producer Flow Control](https://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html) docs and [Per-Destination Policies](https://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies) policies for limiting queue size based on bytes.